# Как записать в MYSQL завтрашнюю дату?

Tags: php, mysql

Имеется потребность записывать в бд значение завтрашней даты.
Как бы мне это реализовать корректно?
Сейчас код выглядит таким образом, но хочу добавить ещё один параметр, который будет писать завтрашнее число в формате 2019-04-05. И да, я уже записываю сегодняшнюю дату, но нужно в отдельный стоблец delivery_date писать завтрашнее число.

```
if (isset($_POST['name'])){
//переменные с формы
$name = strip_tags(trim($_POST['name']));
$surname = strip_tags(trim($_POST['surname']));
$secondname = strip_tags(trim($_POST['secondname']));
$phone = strip_tags(trim($_POST['phone']));
$birthdate = strip_tags(trim($_POST['birthdate']));
$birhtplace = strip_tags(trim($_POST['birhtplace']));
$citizenship = strip_tags(trim($_POST['citizenship']));
$doc = strip_tags(trim($_POST['doc']));
$docid = strip_tags(trim($_POST['docid']));
$docpublish = strip_tags(trim($_POST['docpublish']));
$docdate = strip_tags(trim($_POST['docdate']));
$regterm = strip_tags(trim($_POST['regterm']));
$comment = strip_tags(trim($_POST['comment']));
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$time = date("H:i:s");

//установим соединение с бд
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database)
    or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));
$link->set_charset("utf8");

$sql = "INSERT INTO ".$dbtable." (
    `order_date`, 
    `order_time`, 
    `name`, 
    `surname`, 
    `second_name`, 
    `phone`, 
    `birth_date`,
    `birth_place`, 
    `citizenship`, 
    `doc`, 
    `doc_id`, 
    `doc_publish`, 
    `doc_date`, 
    `term`,
    `adress_register`,
    `comment`
) VALUES (
    '$date', 
    '$time', 
    '$name', 
    '$surname', 
    '$secondname', 
    '$phone', 
    '$birthdate', 
    '$birhtplace', 
    '$citizenship', 
    '$doc', 
    '$docid', 
    '$docpublish', 
    '$docdate', 
    '$regterm',
    '',
    '$comment'
)";

//внесём данные с формы в БД
if (mysqli_query($link, $sql) === TRUE) {
    printf("Успешно\n");
} else {
    printf("Ошибка: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
}

mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: "обязательный комментарий про sql-инъекции"

Comment: `date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date. ' + 1 days')`

Comment: какая разница, в mysql идет дата, или в почту? Учитесь разделять задачи, и не тащить за одним мелким вопросом весь код приложения. Получить завтрашнюю дату - это одна задача, записать какое-либо значение в БД - это другая, которую вы, хоть и криво, но уже, надеюсь, освоили

Comment: @Ипатьев как какая, в mysql дату можно задать как дефолтное значение поля, и вообще не писать никакой логики на пхп.

Comment: можно, но тогда, во-первых, это будет вопрос по mysql, а не php, а во-вторых, генерализованное решение лучше все же делать на рнр.

Comment: я к тому и написал, что возможно автору надо пересмотреть область своего вопроса, относится ли он непосредственно к логике приложения

Comment: @web2k17 там можно [просто `strtotime('tomorrow')`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/datetime.formats.relative.php) написать.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте:

```
(NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: Вопрос про `php`, а не `mysql`.

Comment: @And я отредактировал вопрос после того этот ответ был дан